# How can I use a keyboard shortcut from an bash alias or function ?

Tags: bash, shell-script, keyboard-shortcuts, desktop-shortcuts

Suppose I have an alias or a function defined in my .bashrc, that is not enough complex to write a single script.

Is it possible to bind that alias/function to the shortcuts facility provided by the graphical interface Gnome or xfce4 ?

Comment: What exactly are you doing? `xdotool` can automate X11, if it's graphical widgets that are being fiddled with.

Comment: Hi, iam trying to make some sound control shortcuts as I have several sound card and pulseaudio/alsa can not do what I want from their graphical interface (such as pavucontrol). So basically I want the shortcut to execute the bash command in the backround...

Comment: There's no such thing as "not complex enough" for a script.

Comment: Fair enough....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about Gnome/XFCE specific options, but [xbindkeys] (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xbindkeys) can do this. Configure it with a ~/.xbindkeysrc file and run `xbindkeys` during your X session.

From the default config file

```
 # The format of a command line is:
 #    "command to start"
 #       associated key
```

Where the command can be a shell command, alias, or program (functions didn't seem to work for me).

e.g. I use it to handle my volume keys

```
"~/apps/pa-vol.sh mute"
   XF86AudioMute
"~/apps/pa-vol.sh minus"
   XF86AudioLowerVolume
"~/apps/pa-vol.sh plus"
   XF86AudioRaiseVolume
```

Run `xbindkeys -k` to capture a keystroke for inclusion in your config.